# In terms of python dictionaries is there are way to add multiple values into one key?

Tags: python, dictionary

Just to practice my python skills I am creating a student database program that holds students first and last name, ID, and phone number for a high school but I am encountering a problem. I want to be able to create a dictionary that has a key with multiple values attached to it. Is there a way for me to create a single key with multiple values or is this impossible in Python 3.X? Maybe I'm using the wrong data structure. Who knows. Thanks

Here is my code I have so far

```
def main():

mainDB = {}

loop = True

while loop:

    print('\t\t\t Student Database')
    print('------------------------------------------------------')
    print('K: Key in a record')
    print('D: Display the records')
    option = input('Enter an option: ')

    if option == 'k' or option == 'K':

        # Create a new dictionary
        subDB = {}
        # ask the user to enter student first and last name
        firstLastName = input('Enter student\'s first and last name: ')
        # ask the user to enter the id number and phone number
        idNumber = int(input('Enter student id number: '))
        phoneNumber = int(input('Enter student phone number: '))

        # AT THIS STAGE I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO CREATE A DICTIONARY WITH A SINGLE KEY WITH MULTIPLE VALUES

        # update the main database
        mainDB.update(subDB)

        print('Success')

    elif option == 'd' or option == 'D':

        # display the main database

        print(mainDB)
main()
```

Comment: You can't have multiple values to the same key, but here's a workaround. `{'this is a key':['which','has','many','values','as','a','list']}`

Comment: A spontanious thought is that you could create a class with two values, and add that `d = {'key' : myClass(1, 2)}` for instance - You'd have to access it with `d['key'].var1` (depending on what you name the variables to). The list idea is probably faster/better, but I like calling things by names and not `d['key'][0]`. But it's probably a matter of taste.

Comment: As @BhargavRao suggested, lists can be used for this. However, it seems more proper for you to create a `Student` class and have the value to your keys point to that class object.